# Chainlink external adapter fetch data from my own api server

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I have some problems with using an external adapter to fetch my data on my own API server.

I’m using a template from https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template
Then I modify some of the code, these are where I modify:

```
//parameter
const customParams = {
  action: ['action'],
  value: ['value'],
  endpoint: false
}
```

```
//end point
  if (action=='user') {
    endpoint = `user`
  }
```

```
//url
  const url = `http://localhost:9000/${endpoint}`
  console.log(url)
```

```
//respond
response.data.result = Requester.validateResultNumber(response.data, url)
```

request I send

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" "http://localhost:8080/" --data '{ “id”: 0, "data": {"action": “user”,”value": “5fc95ebeb0d8daafdabd105a” } }'
```

This is the error message I got in the external adapter:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

**I’m quite confused about this problem, where should I find this JSON file?**
It looks like I got a " syntax error in my JSON file.

But I can send this request directly to my API server

```
http://localhost:9000/user/5fc95ebeb0d8daafdabd105a
```

this is the respond

```
  "global_stats": {
    "duo": {
      "kd": 1.1,
      "kills": 20,
      "score": 100
    },
    "solo": {
      "kd": 1.2,
      "kills": 21,
      "score": 101
    }
  },
  "_id": "5fc95ebeb0d8daafdabd105a",
  "name": "mark1",
  "age": 211,
  "__v": 0
}
```

#### Here is the update for comments

In CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7

```
    // mark complete
    complete = true

    if (sync) {
      process.nextTick(invokeCallback)
    } else {
      invokeCallback() // this function is the line 213
    }
```

In CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7

```
  function onEnd (err) {
    if (complete) return
    if (err) return done(err)

    if (length !== null && received !== length) {
      done(createError(400, 'request size did not match content length', {
        expected: length,
        length: length,
        received: received,
        type: 'request.size.invalid'
      }))
    } else {
      var string = decoder
        ? buffer + (decoder.end() || '')
        : Buffer.concat(buffer)
      done(null, string). // this is the line 273
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure what is the means of log the URL, But now I'm trying to figure out once the external adapter request the API server, whether the API server fetch the data, and what it is responding to the adapter. And now I'm using Wireshark trying to do it. I already find that the external did request the API server.

#### Here is the update2 for answer

Hi Patrick, Thank you for your response. I think  I want to use the GET  request because I want to get the value from my API server just like what you present in the youtube video to get the weather of Boston.

When I directly access this URL `http://localhost:9000/user/5fc95ebeb0d8daafdabd105a`

And I got
`{"global_stats":{"duo":{"kd":1.1,"kills":20,"score":100},"solo":{"kd":1.2,"kills":21,"score":101}},"_id":"5fc95ebeb0d8daafdabd105a","name":"mark1","age":211,"__v":0}`

My aim is to let my external adapter to fetch all the data, and respond to me when I use this

`curl -X GET -H "content-type:application/json" "localhost:8080" --data '{ “user”: 0, "data": {"action": “user”,”value": “5fc95ebeb0d8daafdabd105a” } }'`

And I just follow your advice but I still got the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/apple/code/back/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Do you think this error is on my API server? Or it is on the other place. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What is at line 273 and 213?

Comment: And does it log the URL?

Comment: You can add your comments to the comments section down here. It looks like you want your URL to be const url = `http://localhost:9000/${action}/${value}`, I'm not sure why you're setting your URL up otherwise?

Comment: @Patrick Collins Yeah, that's the URL I want. So I want to request to this URL, how can I do with the template? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so you're looking to make a `POST` request and not a get.

1. Add this to your `config` object:

`method = 'post'`

2. Fix how you add the parameters

```
const fsym = validator.validated.data.base.toUpperCase()
  const action = validator.validated.data.action
  const value = validator.validated.data.value
  const url = `http://localhost:8080/${action}/${value}`

  const params = {
  }
```

3. Remove this part entirely

```
  if (action=='user') {
    endpoint = `user`
  }
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank you for your response. I update my reply under the hearer the update2 for answer (I think it has a better format to look at ). I'm confused right now because it is still got the same SyntaxError: Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 2. Is this the problem on my API server? Thank you so much for helping!!

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 2` means it's reading the quote character when it shouldn't be. Perhaps you need to escape the quotes somewhere... One other thought. If you already have a custom API, you could just have the API itself be the external adapter. Does that make sense? Have your API return a "result" and a "jobID" field.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Maybe I should find a way to avoid is " in the JSON file, or I can find a way to let me own to return a result and jobid filed. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you used wrong unicode characters. Instead of `"` (U+0022) you used `“` (U+201C) and `”` (U+201D) characters in `id`, `user`, `value` and `5fc95ebeb0d8daafdabd105a`.  It often happens when you copy/paste code from websites.

Even though they look the same/similar they are completely different and are not interpreted as you expected.

In order to fix the error you should replace them with `"` (U+0022).